# Could not find the following static Boost libraries:boost_thread

Tags: boost, cmake, cgal

I'm trying to compile Boost libraries to use it with CGAL ,
I'm following these guidlines:
[CGAL guidline1](https://www.cgal.org/download/windows.html#Boost)
[CGAL guidline2](http://acg.cs.tau.ac.il/cgal-at-tau/installing-cgal-and-related-programs-on-windows)

after running  -> `.\bootstrap`

Then, ->

```
.\b2 link=static,shared threading=single,multi variant=debug,release
```

I stopped at compiling CGAL using cmake, it's shows the following error:

```
Could not find the following static Boost libraries:
          boost_thread
```

#### cmake screenshot

[image: cmake screenshot]

Cmake error log [here](http://docdro.id/E4ZiNbY)

notice that:  boost_1_67_0\stage\lib folder contains all requires .lib files except "libboost_thread" library file

I appreciate any help , thanks

Comment: What compiler are you using?

Comment: Microsoft visual studio 2013

Comment: If you don't need to build Boost yourself I would start download a precompiled package from the Boost official binary repos `https://sourceforge.net/projects/boost/files/boost-binaries/1.67.0/boost_1_67_0-msvc-12.0-64.exe` or `https://sourceforge.net/projects/boost/files/boost-binaries/1.67.0/boost_1_67_0-msvc-12.0-32.exe` and try if I get that running. Building Boost can be easily sorted out later.

Comment: but , Boost libraries is needed while compiling cgal using cmake , as shown in the screenshot

Comment: It's only Boost, not CGAL. The precompiled Boost package contains a full Boost installation including all libraries, sources and headers! You should not get anything else if you build Boost yourself.

Comment: See the `Prerequisites for Building the 32-bit CGAL Library using Microsoft Visual Studio 2013` section in your first link. Install the package, and point your CMake to it, but do not try to rebuild it with `.\b2 ...`